# Using SpannableString with an EditText to change substring color

Tags: java, android, string, spannablestring

I'm trying to make a code editor in Android Studio.
I'm kind of stuck when I need to change the color of a single keyword(like `if`, `while`, `int` etc.).

So far I've tried using SpannableString, but it doesn't seem to work for an EditText. The app runs and all, but as soon as I type `if`, it freezes and I have to restart. No logcat exceptions.

This is my code:

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.iftext);

    Keywords keys = new Keywords();

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(editText.getText().toString().contains(keys.iff())){

                String r = editText.getText().toString();
                int index = r.indexOf(editText.getText().toString().indexOf(keys.iff()));

                SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(r);
                spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), index , index, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                editText.setText(spannableString);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
```

`keys.iff()` method only returns a string "if"

I wasn't sure about the index so I've tried with "0" and "1" constants and it still freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `TextWatcher` to `editText`. So whenever you type or set chars for `editText`, it will notify in `onTextChanged`.

For first time, you type `if` keyword then code flow goes in inside if the condition.

`editText.setText(spannableString);` this line will again cause textWatcher to notify in onTextChanged. and it creates infinite loop. So Your app hangs or ANR.